# trigger from external mode target to host system

Tags: matlab, simulink

Is it possible to get a trigger signal back from code that's running on the target platform, to the host, so you could run a callback on the local system from the external target.

The only way we now know of doing this is:

- set up a separate network interface, just for sending these trigger signals (which is a lot of work for something quite simple imo)
- continuously checking a parameter of the model on the local system using [get_param](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/toolbox/simulink/slref/get_param.html) and use that to trigger our function locally (but that's obviously not synchronized, which has its own problems)

If anyone wonders why we want to do this: it's for reinforcement learning, and we want to run the learning thingie on the local pc, inspect some values, and then update the controller on the target system.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way that I trigger a local callback from a remote platform is to use a parallel port, I think there are a couple of ways to access parallel ports in Matlab but here is a link to do so [lpt communication in Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/12676-parallel-port-lpt).

The latter part of your question was a little vague since it may/may not have implied that you only need to send a simple trigger to the target PC (and therefore that any information necessary for reinforcement learning is already being distributed appropriately).

Comment: not bad, but that's essentially the same as 'set up a separate network interface'. Thanks for the link, but I can't use it since our pc's don't have parallel ports anymore :(

Comment: Granted many motherboards don't have parallel inputs these days, but if you're looking for something *simpler* than a copper wire between two parallel ports then I'm honestly confused as to what you're expecting.  There are only a handful of hardware outputs on a computer: ethernet/usb/serial/parallel/audio.  By far the easiest thing to do is to set up an ethernet connection, which is by no means difficult.  Other than that you could use either the serial port or run a signal from the audio out to audio in - which I don't recommend due to latency issues and general complexity.

Comment: I think you're searching too much in a hardware solution, because you think the system is embedded and therefore pretty standalone. This is not the case, that's why we're running in [external mode](http://radio.feld.cvut.cz/matlab/toolbox/rtw/rtw_ug/extm2.html): you start/load/stop everything from a local pc through already available ethernet on a remote target. I already listed the possibility of creating a separate channel for the feedback trigger from remote to local pc, and what I'm asking for now, is whether there is a simulink builtin solution for this issue.

Comment: Ah, that will learn me to check the tags on a post.  Missed the Simulink connection completely.